# How to create a date within a Formula in Excel

Tags: excel, date

So what I'm trying to do is create a formula that reflects off of two dates (Start date and end date), if its shorter than 49 days, Find the exact middle date, if it's greater than that number add 30 days to the start date. So far I have the formula down it looks like:

```
=IF(C3-B3>49,IF(B3+30<=C3,"Report Date: "&B3+30,"Report Date: "&C3),"Report Date: "&((C3-B3)/2)+B3)
```

The C Column is the End Date, the B Column is the Start date. What currently comes out for example if the Start date is, 4/2/2017 and the end date is, 2/3/2018, It comes out with, Report Date: 42857

When I want it to actually come out as, 5/2/2017 instead. So how exactly do I go about doing this within the formula itself to automatically set the date for me?

Thanks in advance!

Maykid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Format your formula cell to be a date
2. TEXT(formula, "d/m/yyyy"), but depends what you want to do with it. Some calculations might not work.
3. DATE(YEAR(formula),MONTH(formula),DAY(formula)) In my experience this doesn't give you the result you want with all Excel versions or settings.

Comment: Maykid's output is a string which includes words and dates so point 1 will not work. Point 3 returns the date as a long number, which on it's own is usually recognized by Excel to be a date and is formatted accordingly, again since Maykid's output is not solely a date, it will come out as a number. The only solution is to enclose the bit of formula, which generates the date in `TEXT` formula so in your case it should be `=IF(C3-B3>49,IF(B3+30<=C3,"Report Date: "&TEXT(B3+30,"dd/mm/yy"),"Report Date: "&TEXT(C3,"dd/mm/yy")),"Report Date: "&TEXT(((C3-B3)/2)+B3,"dd/mm/yy"))`

Comment: Perfect! That did exactly what I was wanting to happen! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

The key to this question is to understand how Excel handles dates. Dates in Excel are actually numbers where `1-jan-1900 = 1`. Excel then takes a number and formats it as something more meaningful but it is still, in essence, a number. This way it doesn't matter what your regional setting the number always references the same day.

Excel usually recognizes these numbers, when they are on their own, to be dates and automatically formats them according to your regional settings or custom settings. `42857` with `dd/mmm/yyy` gives `02/May/2017` and with `mm-d-yy` it becomes `05-2-17`

Wit that in mind if a date is included in a string (bit of text) Excel just sees a number and since it's not only a number but also a bit of text, the whole output is considered to be a string and excel cannot format a string like a date.

For this reason you need to enclose the bits in your code that generate the date in the `TEXT` formula. The `TEXT` formula takes the number and formats it accordingly and then spits it out as a string. For this reason, Excel can then no longer do any calculations with this text.

I think the formula for your case should be something like

```
=IF(C3-B3>49,IF(B3+30<=C3,"Report Date: "&TEXT(B3+30,"dd/mm/yy"),"Report Date: "&TEXT(C3,"dd/mm/yy")),"Report Date: "&TEXT(((C3-B3)/2)+B3,"dd/mm/yy"))
```

You can alter the output format by altering the "dd/mm/yy" parts of the formula.

Comment: Surely the second IF is redundant, if C3-B3>49 then you don' t need to test if B3+30<=C3, that must be TRUE....so if you take out that IF and do the other IFs inside the TEXT function you can avoid repetition and shorten formula to: `="Report Date: "&TEXT(IF(C3-B3>49,30,(C3-B3)/2)+B3,"dd/mm/yy")`

Comment: I think you're right, I hadn't actually looked at the conditions and just copied Maykid's complete formula and made the changes. But I like yours better as it's more efficient.